# IOS Admob Interstitial for objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, interstitial

I have implemented interstitial ad on **viewDidLoad**, but I need help with this.
I want Interstitial not to show every time the viewDidLoad appears, example I want it to show one time Yes, One time No. To be something with cases.

- Case 1 show
- Case 2 don't show
- Case 3 show
- ......

Here is my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc] initWithAdUnitID:@"a151b7d316a5c1d"];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    [self.interstitial loadRequest: [GADRequest request]];
}
- (void)interstitialDidReceiveAd:(GADInterstitial *)interstitial {
    [interstitial presentFromRootViewController:self];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do the same kind of one-on, one-off with my ads. I just use a user default to hold a counter. Maybe try the following. The code below is written to be clear so it's a bit long, but you could go in and tighten it up once you know what it's doing (eg. use `adCount += 1;` instead of `adCount = adCount + 1;` etc. Hope this helps!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Call to your helper method
    //Stop viewDidLoad here if the method returns NO

    if (![self _shouldShowInterstitial]) return;

    self.interstitial = [[GADInterstitial alloc];
    initWithAdUnitID:@"a151b7d316a5c1d"];
    self.interstitial.delegate = self;
    [self.interstitial loadRequest: [GADRequest request]];
}

- (BOOL)_shouldShowInterstitial
{
    //1. Recover user default holding a counter
    BOOL retVal = NO;
    NSString *adKey = @"shouldShowInterstitialOnLoadDefaultKey";
    NSInteger adCount = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:adKey];

    //2. If the counter is 1, return YES for showing an ad and reset the count to 0
    if (adCount > 0) {
        retVal = YES;
        adCount = 0;

    //3. If the count is 0, no ad is required, but increment it so next time the ad will show
    } else {
        retVal = NO;
        adCount = adCount + 1;
    }

    //4. Save your defaults
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:adCount forKey:adKey];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

    //5. Return your bool value
    return retVal;
}
```